# How long does the iOS watchdog let the main thread hang for before killing the app?

Tags: ios, watchdog

The watchdog is mentioned [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/qa/qa1693/_index.html), but it's unclear how long it will wait.

(Apple may have purposefully left it undefined, but I am curious how this plays out *in practice*. It may well have not changed for several years.)